# Will my CRA Canada carryover amount cover this eventuality?

Tags: taxes, canada

I have federal and provincial carryover amounts with CRA (tuition amounts). 
I assume on my TD1 Federal and Provincial credits return forms that my spouse's estimated income for the current year is zero because it will potentially be the case. My taxes will be lower in this year. But if her income will be higher than has been assumed I will owe money to CRA. Will my carry over amounts cover this kind of eventuality?

Comment: Do you mean offset rather than cover?  Cover would seem to require that the amounts be sufficiently large.  But you don't tell us numbers for anything except the possibility that the spouse's income will be zero.

Comment: Yes, I mean offset. I calculated that if I report on my TD1 forms that my wife will have no income for this year then my Federal and Ontario taxes, together will be around $4000, however if she finds a job and earns income then I will have to pay higher taxes, perhaps around $6000. So my question is, will the $2000 difference be offset by my tuition carry over amount which is sizable, in the event she finds  job sometime this year. Thanks.